# Do people know of their death in advance?

Tags: islamic-basis, death

According to people I used to hear that when a person who is going to die, he will come to know about it before 40 days of his death day? Is there any Islamic basis for this belief?

Comment: If this were true I'm sure it would be common knowledge, and no-one would ever be shocked by a premature death. This, unfortunately, is not the case.

Answer (score -1):

There are two things which a human does not know about their life. One is when they will get married and the other is they will die. There is no Ayat is the Qur'an or Hadith which mentions that a person will feel or know that they will die before the time comes.

Comment: Well, if we think logically about it there are plenty of other things that a person doesn't know about his life.

Comment: @BleedingFingers Yes you are right but those are the two that I know are mentioned. I don't think the down vote was needed since I did answer the question "There is no Ayat is the Qur'an or Hadith which mentions that a person will feel or know that they will die before the time comes."

Comment: @Zohal, I agree with you. Actually your answer is true as you pointed out that there is no verse or hadith that... / Thus there could not be another answer, right? / Besides, in order to get +vote : I recommend you to take a minor edition on your appropriate answer. (for instance say: there are things among marriage and death ... /  Anyhow I really appreciate your brief good answer.